# How can I display all the blogs where this user is editor in Wordpress Multisite?

Tags: user-roles, user-meta

[Very similar question with correct answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72116/how-can-i-display-all-the-blogs-where-this-user-is-administrator-in-wordpress-mu)

I guess my question is simple, I run multisite and on some blog I want to display <> thing
The link I posted does not work for me, but it is marked as correct, what's the problem?

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_user_blogs_by_role' ) ) {
/**
 * Get all blog IDs where the user has the given role.
 *
 * @param  int $user_id
 * @param  string $role
 * @return array
 */
function get_user_blogs_by_role( $user_id, $role )
{
    $blogs = array ();
    $regex = '~' . $GLOBALS['wpdb']->base_prefix . '(\d+)_capabilities~';
    $meta  = get_user_meta( $user_id );

    if ( ! $meta )
        return array ();

    foreach ( $meta as $key => $value )
    {
        if ( preg_match( $regex, $key, $matches ) )
        {
            $roles = maybe_unserialize( $meta[$key][0] );

            // the number is a string
            if ( isset( $roles[$role] ) and '1' === $roles[$role] )
                $out[] = $matches[1];
        }
    }

    return $out;
}
}
$blogs = get_user_blogs_by_role( 1, 'administrator' );
var_dump( $blogs ); // Array ( 2, 14, 90 )
```

the code returns **NULL**

Comment: That depends where you are using the code. Put the function in `functions.php` and the other two lines of code in `footer.php`, does it work?

Comment: There is a typo in that code: the variable names `$out` and `$blogs` don't match. I have fixed that in the original post.

Comment: thanks, it does not return NULL but still returns empty array.

Comment: I did insert main code to functions.php and quering that function from footer (after wp_footer() )

Comment: @toscho, it only works for me if using `'1' == $roles[$role]` (not the identical operator, but a simple equal).

Comment: Update: I'm [seeing a variation](http://cl.ly/image/2414330i2y0p) in `$user_object->caps`, sometimes it's `'1'`, sometimes `true`.

Comment: @brasofilo Ah, I missed that, thanks. Fixed in my original code with `1 === (int) $roles[$role]`.

Comment: thanks now everything works perfecto,
special thanks to brasofilo <3